# Как писать Jenkinsfile что бы он начал работать

Tags: c#, cmd, jenkins

Пытаюсь создать Jenkinsfile и сдлеать в нем pipeline что бы когда делаешь изменения в проекте jenkins все тянул с гита и выполнял тесты.
На данный момент сделал следующее.
Добавил файл в проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И написал в нем следующий код (думал его будет достаточно).

```
pipeline {
    agent any      
    
    stages {       
            stage('Test') {
            steps 
            {
                 echo 'dotnet test --filter Name~"SwitchLanguage"'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю это все в Jenkins то получаю следующий результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках Jenkins следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сориентируйте что необходимо добавить.
И какие все же использовать команды для шагов. Подойдут ли стандартные для консоли в dotnet.

После исправления в меню Jenkins имени ветки и того где лежит Jenkinsfile
Лог показал следующее.

```
Started by user ----
Obtained YandexTraineeProject/Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/-/YandexTraineeProject.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, publishChecks, pwd, pwsh, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstable, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, warnError, withChecks, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, withGradle, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allBranchesSame, allOf, allure, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, buildRetention, buildUser, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, command, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, dotnetBuild, dotnetClean, dotnetCommandCompleted, dotnetDiagnostic, dotnetListPackage, dotnetNuGetDelete, dotnetNuGetPush, dotnetPack, dotnetPublish, dotnetRestore, dotnetTest, dotnetToolRestore, dotnetsdk, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, email-ext, envVars, envVarsFilter, environment, equals, expression, extendedEmailPublisher, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, fingerprints, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubExcludeArchivedRepositories, gitHubExcludePublicRepositories, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubPullRequestDiscovery, gitHubSshCheckout, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTopicsFilter, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitTagDiscovery, github, githubPush, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installDotNetSDK, installSource, isRestartedRun, javadoc, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, junitTestResultStorage, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenGlobalConfig, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, msbuild, msbuildError, msbuildWarning, mstest, myView, namedBranchesDifferent, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, none, not, nunit, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, pruneTags, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimit, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, requestor, resourceRoot, retainOnlyVariables, run, runParam, sSHLauncher, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, ssh, sshPublicKey, sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, suppressAutomaticTriggering, swapSpace, tag, teamSlugFilter, text, textParam, timestamper, timestamperConfig, timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, triggeredBy, unsecured, untrusted, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, withDotNet, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:216)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

В поле `Branch Specifier` у вас написано неправильно название ветки, должно быть `dev` или `*/dev` (на это намекают сообщения в логах). Также проверьте чтобы `Script Path` указывал на правильный путь к `Jenkinsfile`, если он у вас в корне репозитория лежит все ок, но если в другой папке это нужно будет указать.

Comment: А что на счет самого содержания Jenkisfile там шаги верные? или нужно еще писать что бы с репозитория качал проект ?

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк если вы просто хотите вывести в консоль сообщение, то верные, но никакие тесты запускаться не будут, качать проект по идее не нужно, т.к. он уже будет

Comment: Ну я поправил то на что вы обратили внимание. Лог поменялся. А как сделать что бы началось выполнение теста который у меня в шаге прописан ? Добавил новый лог в описание.

Comment: @ПавелПанасюк чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы пересохраните `Jenkinsfile` как utf-8, т.к. utf-8 with bom не работает https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41476

Comment: а для того чтобы понять как писать правильно команды в stage можно поискать примеры

Comment: а как его можно пересохранить ?